# Sending inputs to email? WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms, email, input, send

I'm working on a simple WinForm project where I have a textBox that the user inputs his name.
When he clicks on a button I want to be able to send this input to an email address or something like that.

Would this be possible? If so how do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried Googling anything like "send email with .NET" or "C# send email"?  There's no shortage of examples out there on how to use `System.Net.Mail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following code serves to Send an Email with a custom SMTP Client:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.customsmtp.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("fromEmail@fromemail.com");
                mail.To.Add("toemail@toemail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Your Subject";
                mail.Body = "Your Textbox Here!";
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Seems some problem!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

The sample below to send e-mail from your gmail account using your gmail username and password:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace GMailSample
{
    class SimpleSmtpSend
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);           
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("YourGmailUserName@gmail.com", "[ Your full name here]");           
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("your recipient e-mail address", "Your recepient name");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent using gmail as a relay server ";
            message.Subject = "Gmail test email with SSL and Credentials";
            NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential("YourGmailUserName@gmail.com", "YourPassword", "");           
            client.Credentials = myCreds;
            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception is:" + ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope This Helps!